# C# Xamarin.Android Calling Dialogfragment from recyclerView

Tags: c#, android, android-recyclerview, xamarin.android, android-dialogfragment

I would like to display diaglog fragment by clicking a button/imageView (By clicking the sAddButton)from recyclerView. But when I clicked the button nothing shows up.
How do I achieve that here is my code.

My RecyclerView Adapter
I added an pulic eventhandler in myadapter (StockInItemClick)
then created a delegate method to invoke the eventhandler(OnStockInClick)
then pass the delegate method as parameter on my adapterview holder
then Implement the delegate method on my adapterview holder.

```
internal class StocksAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
{
    public event EventHandler<StocksAdapterClickEventArgs> ItemClick;
    public event EventHandler<StocksAdapterClickEventArgs> ItemLongClick;
    public event EventHandler<StocksAdapterClickEventArgs> StockInItemClick;
    List<Products> items;

    public StocksAdapter(List<Products> data)
    {
        items = data;
    }

    
    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {

        //Setup your layout here
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.stock_rView, parent, false);
        //var id = Resource.Layout.__YOUR_ITEM_HERE;
        //itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).
        //       Inflate(id, parent, false);
        

        var vh = new StocksAdapterViewHolder(itemView, OnClick, OnLongClick, OnStockInClick);
        return vh;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position)
    {
        
        var holder = viewHolder as StocksAdapterViewHolder;
        //holder.TextView.Text = items[position];
        holder.sNameText.Text = items[position].PName;
        holder.sQtyText.Text = items[position].QtyonHand;
    }

    public override int ItemCount => items.Count;

    void OnClick(StocksAdapterClickEventArgs args) => ItemClick?.Invoke(this, args);
    void OnLongClick(StocksAdapterClickEventArgs args) => ItemLongClick?.Invoke(this, args);
    void OnStockInClick(StocksAdapterClickEventArgs args) => StockInItemClick?.Invoke(this, args);
}

public class StocksAdapterViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    //public TextView TextView { get; set; }

    public TextView sNameText { get; set; }
    public TextView sQtyText { get; set; }
    public ImageButton sAddButton { get; set; }

    public StocksAdapterViewHolder(View itemView, Action<StocksAdapterClickEventArgs> clickListener,
                        Action<StocksAdapterClickEventArgs> longClickListener,
                        Action<StocksAdapterClickEventArgs> stockInClickListener) : base(itemView)
    {
        //TextView = v;
        sNameText = (TextView)itemView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.sNameTView);
        sQtyText = (TextView)itemView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.qtyonhandTView);
        sAddButton = (ImageButton)itemView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.addButton);

        itemView.Click += (sender, e) => clickListener(new StocksAdapterClickEventArgs { View = itemView, Position = AdapterPosition });
        itemView.LongClick += (sender, e) => longClickListener(new StocksAdapterClickEventArgs { View = itemView, Position = AdapterPosition });
        sAddButton.Click += (sender, e) => longClickListener(new StocksAdapterClickEventArgs { View = itemView, Position = AdapterPosition });
        
    }
}

public class StocksAdapterClickEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public View View { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }
}
```

my code in activity
I implement the eventhandler
then on the event onlcick event(Adapter_StockInItemClick) I called the
dialog fragment.

```
private void SetupRecyclerView()
{
    stockRView.SetLayoutManager(new Android.Support.V7.Widget.LinearLayoutManager(stockRView.Context));
    adapter = new StocksAdapter(StockList);
    adapter.StockInItemClick += Adapter_StockInItemClick;
    stockRView.SetAdapter(adapter);
}

private void Adapter_StockInItemClick(object sender, StocksAdapterClickEventArgs e)
{
    Products thisproducts = StockList[e.Position];
    addNewStockInProductsFragment = new AddNewStockInProductsFragment(thisproducts);
    var trans = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
    addNewStockInProductsFragment.Show(trans, "StockIn");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem

```
sAddButton.Click += (sender, e) => longClickListener(new StocksAdapterClickEventArgs { View = itemView, Position = AdapterPosition });
```

shouldbe (deleteClickListener) not (longClickListener)

```
sAddButton.Click += (sender, e) => deleteClickListener(new StocksAdapterClickEventArgs { View = itemView, Position = AdapterPosition });
```